# Make all children of div to take up 100% height and 100% width so that only the first is visible

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `div` with multiple `div`s in it and I want each and every one of the children `div`s to take up 100% height and 100% width so that only the first of them is actually visible (parent has `overflow: hidden`) and the rest are to the right of it, but hidden. When I try to give them all `height: 100%; width: 100%;` they don't get the full width of the parent, but instead the full width gets split among them so they're all visible.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

.children {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#child1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#child2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children" id="child1"></div>
  <div class="children" id="child2"></div>
</div>
```

**E: Added my code.**

Comment: so how you are adding height and width using js? 
you dont need to do this kind of hack you can add a css display:none for all other child divs and width:100% for the first one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set for children: `flex-shrink: 0;`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want them to be side by side. In this case, the first one will be visible and the rest will be out of the parent visible area. You can make the children inline blocks and strop the text wrapping on the parent. This will give you the effect you want.

I will use `overflow: scroll` instead of `overflow: hidden` in my example below, just so you can scroll and see the other boxes.

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #f00;
  height: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #0ff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child">Child 2</div>
  <div class="child">Child 3</div>
  <div class="child">Child 4</div>
  <div class="child">Child 5</div>
</div>
```

Notice that there are gaps between the children. This is because white space between inline object is converted to one space. To get rid of it, remove the white space between the children. You can do that, by physically removing it, or converting it to a comment:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #f00;
  height: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #0ff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child 1</div><div
       class="child">Child 2</div><div
       class="child">Child 3</div><div
       class="child">Child 4</div><div
       class="child">Child 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the `flex: 0 0 100%` on the `.children` where you prevent *flex-items* from *growing* and *shrinking*, and set their *initial width* to `100%`:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  /*flex-direction: row; by default*/
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.children {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  /*width: 100%;*/
  /*position: relative;*/
}

#child1 {
  background: red;
}

#child2 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children" id="child1"></div>
  <div class="children" id="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `max-height` of parent same to `height` of child

```css
.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent {
  max-height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Notice how we’re using the same interface (subscribe) to deal with totally different types of operations (including the document listener we added in the previous example). This is one of the major strengths of using Observables. We don’t need to wire
    our brains differently. If the data can be thought of as evented, stream or async, we can wrap it in an Observable.</div>
  <div class="child">Notice how we’re using the same interface (subscribe) to deal with totally different types of operations (including the document listener we added in the previous example). This is one of the major strengths of using Observables. We don’t need to wire
    our brains differently. If the data can be thought of as evented, stream or async, we can wrap it in an Observable.</div>
  <div class="child">Notice how we’re using the same interface (subscribe) to deal with totally different types of operations (including the document listener we added in the previous example). This is one of the major strengths of using Observables. We don’t need to wire
    our brains differently. If the data can be thought of as evented, stream or async, we can wrap it in an Observable.</div>
  <div class="child">Notice how we’re using the same interface (subscribe) to deal with totally different types of operations (including the document listener we added in the previous example). This is one of the major strengths of using Observables. We don’t need to wire
    our brains differently. If the data can be thought of as evented, stream or async, we can wrap it in an Observable.</div>
  <div class="child">Notice how we’re using the same interface (subscribe) to deal with totally different types of operations (including the document listener we added in the previous example). This is one of the major strengths of using Observables. We don’t need to wire
    our brains differently. If the data can be thought of as evented, stream or async, we can wrap it in an Observable.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The div tag is a block level element and has default behavior that displays as a block. You probably should think about using a display : none command so that the elements do not take up space. Almost every element in CSS has default behavior that you have to change if you want an element to behave differently. If CSS doesn't understand a command it just ignores it and continues on as if no command was issued. CSS behaves like this so that the rendering does not come to a screeching halt whenever an error is encountered. That is in sharp contrast to programming languages where you would have an exception or error thrown. It sounds like the behavior you desire is for the non-visible elements not to take up space in the containing element which would be accomplished with the display:none attribute. You can always use the getComputedStyle() on an element in the console to view what styles are actually being applied to an element